# Equidimensional affine ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

A scheme is equidimensional iff all its irreducible components have the same dimension.

A ring is tell equidimensional iff all its minimal primes have the same dimension (that is $\text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{p})$)  and all its maximal primes have the same codimension (height).

For a affine scheme these definitions seem different: the dimension of irreducible components corresponds to the definition of the minimal primes. But why is there a condition over the maximal primes (codimension of points)?

Comment: I think this is a matter of terminology. For me an *equidimensional* ring satisfies only the first condition. The second condition means that the ring is *equicodimensional*.

Comment: @uder26857 I don't see what a not equicodimensional equidimensional scheme looks like (geometrically). Can you give me a example? How can codimension of point not be equal with dimension of irreducible components equal?

Comment: Equidimensional finitely generated algebras over a field are equicodimensional (if this is what you asked!). In my first comment I talked about *rings*.

Comment: An example of equidimensional ring which is not equicodimensional is $K[[X]][Y]$: the maximal ideal $(XY-1)$ has height one.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks! For finitely generated algebra over a field it's come from the Neother Normalization lemme I guess. I don't see any clear geometric proof of this fact... but as usual answer is in algebra! Thanks for your counterexample I have to study it.

Comment: @user26857 Ok I see algebrically from where comes your counterexample: in $k[X,Y]$ the ideal $(XY-1)$ has height 1 (it's a curve) but is not maximal: it's contained for example in $(X-1,Y-1)$ (or the quotient is $k[X,X^{-1}]$ which is not a field). But in $k[[X]][Y]$ it is maximal because the quotient is $k[[X]][X^{-1}]$ which is a field (yes?). As the other curves stay not maximal it's works. How to think at it geometrically? It's to do with completion and I don't manage this well... I would have take $k[X,Y]_{(XY-1)}$ but it's kill the other curves!